# Mongo DB SORTING data nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

i created a code that Backsup/Deletes and Inserts information from the Third Party API every 24hours to update the Third party api changes daily on the database.

how can i sort the information i get from the MongoDB by which score changed the most?

***API LOOKS LIKE***

```
 {
        "_id": "6365e1dbde0dd3639536f4b7",
        "position": 1,
        "id": "105162",
        "score": 2243536903,
        "__v": 0
    },
```

***MY CODE***

```
app.get('/api/TopFlops', async (req, res) => {
    const topflops = await TopFlops.find({}).sort({_id: +1}).limit(5)
    res.json(topflops);
 })
```

***CODE TO INSERT DATA FROM THE 3RD PARTY API TO DB***

```
cron.schedule('59 23 * * *', async () => {

    const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
        id: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
    
    });
    
    const Post = mongoose.model('players', postSchema);
    
    async function getPosts() {
        const getPlayers = await fetch("http://localhost:3008/api/players");
        const response = await getPlayers.json();
        for( let i = 0;i < response.players.length; i++){
    
    const post = new Post({
        id: response.players[i]['id'],
        name: response.players[i]['name'],
        status: response.players[i]['status'],
    });
    post.save();
    
    
        }
    
    }
    console.log("Table submitted successfully")
    
    await getPosts();

});
```

***CODE TO FETCH API***

```
  const [playerName, setPlayerName] = useState([]);
  const [playerRank, setPlayerRank] = useState([]);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState([]);
  const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [size, setSize] = useState(perPage);
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(1);
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState();

  const fetchData = () => {
    const playerAPI = 'http://localhost:3001/api/topflops';
    const playerRank = 'http://localhost:3001/api/topflops';

    const getINFOPlayer = axios.get(playerAPI)
    const getPlayerRank = axios.get(playerRank)
    axios.all([getINFOPlayer, getPlayerRank]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) => {
        const allDataPlayer = allData[0].data
        const getINFOPlayerRank = allData[1].data
        const newPlayer = allDataPlayer.map(name => {
          const pr = getINFOPlayerRank.find(rank => name.id === rank.id)


          return {
            id: name.id,
            name: name.name,
            alliance: name.alliance,
            position: pr?.position,
            score: pr?.score
          }
        })

        setPlayerName(allDataPlayer)
        setPlayerRank(getINFOPlayerRank)

        console.log(getINFOPlayerRank)
        console.log(newPlayer)
        setPlayer(newPlayer)
      })
    )
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  const getData = (current, pageSize) => {
    // Normally you should get the data from the server
    return player?.slice((current - 1) * pageSize, current * pageSize);
  };
```

Comment: Do you mean to sort by which score changed the most? Or just highest score? Because you can change your sort to `.sort({score: 1})` instead of using the id. Remove the "+" sign from your sort. This is not valid MongoDB syntax. It recognizes only "1" and "-1".

Comment: by which score changed the most, yes sorry im gonna update the question thanks for answer !

Comment: There are methods to do this natively in MongoDB. Look into the [Change Streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) and [Change Events](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/) sections in MongoDB docs.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add another field to your schema called "changes" and each time an update method is run on score, automatically +1 to that value. Then query and sort by "changes" as needed.

Comment: is there any guide on how to do the alternative way?

Comment: Can you post part of your current update logic as you fetch the API and save to your DB?

Comment: How is a change in score captured and calculated? Is there a new document that is inserted (with the same `id` and a different `__v` value perhaps) that contains the new value? Or is the `score` of the existing document updated in place (with no history captured)? Over what timeframe will you be looking at the changes? Are you looking at total changes (if there are more than one change) or just the largest single change? Need to know more about your current setup and your desired logic in order to assist.

Comment: So score is not persisted to your database at any point? Also noticing that you are making separate axios requests to the exact same endpoint. Can you not make this in one request and map your data from there?

Comment: yes im making two request because the data is separate on 3rd api has data for names and the other api has data for highscore, so i run this code to match id with id and show name